# Using the phrase 'rise to the level of [sth]'

Tags: grammar, phrase-usage

> At a number of state-owned factories, workers staged anti-government protests. Most of them, however, didn't rise to the level of **strike/a strike/strikes**.

Which should I prefer? And how idiomatic is the phrase 'rise to the level of [sth]'? Google News didn't find many matches (in quotes).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use either "a strike" or "strikes" depending on the hypothetical situation you have in mind: either the protests leading to a single strike or the protests leading to a series of strikes (or an environment in which strikes routinely occur). You wouldn't use "a strike" if even a single strike occurred, though.

"Rise to the level of" used in this way would sound natural to a native English speaker. You can look at [Google Scholar](https://scholar.google.com/scholar?hl=en&as_sdt=0%2C5&q=%22rise+to+the+level+of%22&btnG=) to see how the phrase is used (with both single and plural phrases) in the academic literature.